# Keychain: Beachball When Visualizing Password

Tags: macos, password, permission, keychain

I can use the passwords in the keychain when opening a program, but if I try to display the password in the keychain entry I get asked for the root password. When entering the root password the beachball is displayed and never disappears. The program does not completely hang because I can abort the operation with <kbd>esc</kbd>. Still while the beachball is present I can't do anything else. Other passwords which are stored in the cloud (e.g. wifi pw) can be accessed.

The file rights are:
`-rw-r--r--@ 1 username  staff  442368  8 Dez 18:53 username.keychain`

I recently updated my Mac to El Capitan and repaired the file permissions with *Disk Utility*.

Answer (score 1):

It is a problem with MagicPrefs and el capitan:
https://discussions.apple.com/message/29270520#29270520

Disabling MagicPrefs does the trick.

As always after an hour trying and googling I found the answer 5min after a post ;-)